# How do I convert this R script into a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am really keen to transfer some of my scripts to R Shiny environments for my (non-R-trained) colleagues to use in my absence.

There is one script in particular that I really want to upload and there are three distinct sections:

- Import data
- Restructure data
- Visualise results

I have no idea where to start in terms of building/converting the code into a Shiny app, but my idea is that a user uploads a .csv file (that will always be in the same format), and then the app proceeds to restructure the data and then provides a visualisation.

I have looked at tutorials online but none of them seem to cover quite what I am looking to do here.

Some guidance on how to achieve this would be wonderful.

**Sample dataset:**

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17683, 17683, 17683, 17683, 
17684, 17684, 17684, 17685, 17686, 17686, 17687, 17687, 17687, 
17687, 17688, 17689, 17689, 17689, 17689), class = "Date"), type = c("Completed", 
"Completed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", 
"Missed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", 
"Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", 
"Completed", "Missed"), retailer_code = c("GGdwO3HFDV", "Tj8vwJvyH1", 
"npqPjZyMy5", "GGdwO3HFDV", "npqPjZyMy5", "GGdwO3HFDV", "npqPjZyMy5", 
"npqPjZyMy5", "npqPjZyMy5", "npqPjZyMy5", "1mRdYODJBH", "Tj8vwJvyH1", 
"npqPjZyMy5", "npqPjZyMy5", "Tj8vwJvyH1", "Tj8vwJvyH1", "npqPjZyMy5", 
"HbNaIqdedB", "npqPjZyMy5"), count = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

**My code:**

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(ggplot2)

# Read in data
eu_chats <- read.csv("20180601_20180607_EU.csv", sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Rename columns
colnames(eu_chats) <- c("date", "type", "retailer_code", "count")

# Remove time from date column
eu_chats$date <- gsub(", 00:00:00.000", "", eu_chats$date)
eu_chats$date <- gsub("st", "", eu_chats$date)
eu_chats$date <- gsub("nd", "", eu_chats$date)
eu_chats$date <- gsub("rd", "", eu_chats$date)
eu_chats$date <- gsub("th", "", eu_chats$date)

eu_chats$date <- as.Date(eu_chats$date, format='%B %d %Y')

# Label missed anc completed chats accordingly
eu_chats$type[eu_chats$type == "conversation-auto-archived"] <- "Missed"
eu_chats$type[eu_chats$type == "conversation-archived"] <- "Completed"

# Add new columns (intialise to 0 or "retailer")
eu_chats$retailer <- ""

# Identify France, Germany & UK stores
eu_chats$retailer[eu_chats$retailer_code == "npqPjZyMy5"] <- "Retailer1"
eu_chats$retailer[eu_chats$retailer_code == "HbNaIqdedB"] <- "Retailer2"
eu_chats$retailer[eu_chats$retailer_code == "1mRdYODJBH"] <- "Retailer3"
eu_chats$retailer[eu_chats$retailer_code == "GGdwO3HFDV"] <- "Retailer4"
eu_chats$retailer[eu_chats$retailer_code == "Tj8vwJvyH1"] <- "Retailer5"
eu_chats$retailer_code <- NULL

# Visualise chats

eu_chats %>%
  spread(type, count, fill = 0) %>%   # Spread the count column in missed and completed
  mutate(Total = Completed + Missed) %>%   # Create the Total column
  ggplot(aes(as.Date(date, tz = "Europe/London"), Total)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = "Total"),
           colour = "black", width = 0.75) + # total bar (with stat = "identity")
  geom_col(aes(y = Missed, fill = "Missed"),
           colour = "black", width = 0.75) + # missed bar
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Total chats:", Total)), # add total label
            hjust = -0.05, vjust = 0.7, size = 3.5) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Missed chats:", Missed, "(", round(Missed/Total*100, 2), "%)")), # add missed label and calculate percentage
            hjust = -0.05, vjust = -0.7, size = 3.5, colour = "red") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "",  # Manual fill scale
                    values = c("Total" = "forestgreen", "Missed" = "red")) +
  facet_grid(retailer~.) +  # Displayed per retailer
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(eu_chats$count) * 2)) + # Make labels visible
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", name = "Date") +
  ggtitle(paste("Missed Chats (", min(eu_chats$date), "-", max(eu_chats$date), ")")) +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: The data has 5 columns, but you are only assigning 4 colnames. "retailer" is missing and with the `as.Date()` conversion I am getting NA values. This format would work for me `format="%Y-%m-%d"`.

Comment: Apologies, I uploaded the processed dataset - I have now updated the code and changed the `dput`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didnt provide the csv-file, I didnt test the following code. But it should be a start, although there are several ways to achieve your desired behaviour.

- I am doing **Importing and Restructuring** in a `reactive` object.
- And the **Visualizing** is inside a `renderPlot`.

I am not using the fileInput in the code, I am taking the hardcoded data from your dput output. If you want to use the fileInput instead, uncomment the 2 lines at the top of the reactive (Its commented in the code too).

The Date-format is still giving me NA values.

So I changed the format from `'%B %d %Y'` to `"%Y-%m-%d"`

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

data = structure(list(date = structure(c(17683, 17683, 17683, 17683, 
                                         17684, 17684, 17684, 17685, 17686, 17686, 17687, 17687, 17687, 
                                         17687, 17688, 17689, 17689, 17689, 17689), class = "Date"), type = c("Completed", 
                                                                                                              "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", 
                                                                                                              "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", 
                                                                                                              "Completed", "Missed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", 
                                                                                                              "Completed", "Missed"), retailer_code = c("GGdwO3HFDV", "Tj8vwJvyH1", 
                                                                                                                                                        "npqPjZyMy5", "GGdwO3HFDV", "npqPjZyMy5", "GGdwO3HFDV", "npqPjZyMy5", 
                                                                                                                                                        "npqPjZyMy5", "npqPjZyMy5", "npqPjZyMy5", "1mRdYODJBH", "Tj8vwJvyH1", 
                                                                                                                                                        "npqPjZyMy5", "npqPjZyMy5", "Tj8vwJvyH1", "Tj8vwJvyH1", "npqPjZyMy5", 
                                                                                                                                                        "HbNaIqdedB", "npqPjZyMy5"), count = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -19L))


ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("inFile", "Upload a csv-file"),
  selectInput("header", label = "Set header to TRUE or FALSE", choices = c(TRUE, FALSE)),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  eu_chats_react <- reactive({

    ## Uncomment the following 2 lines when using the fileInput!!
    # req(input$inFile$datapath)
    # eu_chats <- read.csv(input$inFile$datapath, header = as.logical(input$header))

    eu_chats <- data

    # Rename columns
    colnames(eu_chats) <- c("date", "type", "retailer_code", "count")

    # Remove time from date column
    eu_chats$date <- gsub(", 00:00:00.000", "", eu_chats$date)
    eu_chats$date <- gsub("st", "", eu_chats$date)
    eu_chats$date <- gsub("nd", "", eu_chats$date)
    eu_chats$date <- gsub("rd", "", eu_chats$date)
    eu_chats$date <- gsub("th", "", eu_chats$date)


    ## Other Date Format !!!!
    # eu_chats$date <- as.Date(eu_chats$date, format='%B %d %Y')
    eu_chats$date <- as.Date(eu_chats$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

    # Label missed anc completed chats accordingly
    eu_chats$type[eu_chats$type == "conversation-auto-archived"] <- "Missed"
    eu_chats$type[eu_chats$type == "conversation-archived"] <- "Completed"

    # Add new columns (intialise to 0 or "retailer")
    eu_chats$retailer <- ""

    # Identify France, Germany & UK stores
    eu_chats$retailer[eu_chats$retailer_code == "npqPjZyMy5"] <- "Retailer1"
    eu_chats$retailer[eu_chats$retailer_code == "HbNaIqdedB"] <- "Retailer2"
    eu_chats$retailer[eu_chats$retailer_code == "1mRdYODJBH"] <- "Retailer3"
    eu_chats$retailer[eu_chats$retailer_code == "GGdwO3HFDV"] <- "Retailer4"
    eu_chats$retailer[eu_chats$retailer_code == "Tj8vwJvyH1"] <- "Retailer5"
    eu_chats$retailer_code <- NULL

    eu_chats
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    eu_chats_react() %>%
      spread(type, count, fill = 0) %>%   # Spread the count column in missed and completed
      mutate(Total = Completed + Missed) %>%   # Create the Total column
      ggplot(aes(as.Date(date, tz = "Europe/London"), Total)) + 
      geom_col(aes(fill = "Total"),
               colour = "black", width = 0.75) + # total bar (with stat = "identity")
      geom_col(aes(y = Missed, fill = "Missed"),
               colour = "black", width = 0.75) + # missed bar
      geom_text(aes(label = paste("Total chats:", Total)), # add total label
                hjust = -0.05, vjust = 0.7, size = 3.5) + 
      geom_text(aes(label = paste("Missed chats:", Missed, "(", round(Missed/Total*100, 2), "%)")), # add missed label and calculate percentage
                hjust = -0.05, vjust = -0.7, size = 3.5, colour = "red") + 
      scale_fill_manual(name = "",  # Manual fill scale
                        values = c("Total" = "forestgreen", "Missed" = "red")) +
      facet_grid(retailer~.) +  # Displayed per retailer
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(eu_chats_react()$count) * 2)) + # Make labels visible
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", name = "Date") +
      ggtitle(paste("Missed Chats (", min(eu_chats_react()$date), "-", max(eu_chats_react()$date), ")")) +
      coord_flip()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

With the package `shinyBS` you can put the plot in a modal, but its not resizable, you may have to look at `shinyjqui` for that or any interactive plotting library (plotly, highcharter, RCharts etc..)

But maybe thats fine for you, just add the `library(shinyBS)` and exchange the ui-function to:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("inFile", "Upload a csv-file"),
      selectInput("header", label = "Set header to TRUE or FALSE", choices = c(TRUE, FALSE)),
      actionButton("go", "Go")
                 ),
    mainPanel(
      bsModal("modalExample", "Your plot", "go", size = "large",plotOutput("plot"))
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you - I have added the `dput` now.

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to run the app: `Error in func(fname, ...) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.`.

Comment: I was missing the `input$ ` for the csv-input-file. Just edited the answer

Comment: This is very good, thank you.  I have one question - would it be possible to have the chart appear outside of the app window?

Comment: Just made another tiny adaptation.. When using read.csv, you have to put `input$header` inside a `as.logical()`, as it is not able to read characters apparently. What do you mean outside of the app window? Where is outside? :)

Comment: I mean as in the chart appears in a separate window to the main app window and not beneath it.  Similar to how you can click on "Zoom" in RStudio. Also, the app keeps producing the same chart no matter which .csv I import - why might that be?

Comment: New edit.. Well, my code uses the dput-output that you provided with `eu_chats <- data`. If you want to use the fileInput, uncomment out the lines in the reactive (its documented in the code too) and delete the line with `eu_chats <- data`

Comment: So I did that (uncommenting lines and commenting out the other) and am receiving an error now when I read a .csv in that says Error: argument is of length zero.  Or I get this error:  `Duplicate identifiers for rows (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10), (1, 9), (7, 8)`

Comment: I think that comes from the Date-format. When I use my format, the error does not appear. When I use your format, i get the same error `Duplicate identifiers`.  And I noticed that the csv file must be saved without row.names (and maybe use `fread` instead of `read.csv`?)

Comment: Yes, I used my date format and I also used `data.table::fread` - that worked perfectly. Thanks!